# How can I move a conditional breakpoint in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, conditional-breakpoint

I've set a conditional breakpoint on the *wrong* line. I would like to move it up one line. Is that even possible? I know that I can always copy paste the condition into a new breakpoint at the correct line, but just drag &drop would be more convenient.

Example:

```
private void loopOverInternalList(Object findThis) {
    int numberFound = 0; //I want conditional breakpoint here.
    for(Object listItem : internalList) { // Breakpoint [findThis.getSomeProperty() == true]
        // do something...
    }
}
```

In the example Eclipse will break for each item in the internalList, while if it breaks on the numberFound definition it should break only once. Which is more convenient in my current scenario.

Comment: Copy the conditional breakpoint definition and Create a new conditional breakpoint. Then paste the definition in the newly created conditional breakpoint.

Comment: Probably u will get lucky when the next release of eclipse comes along. I have heard, they are going to re release it .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight next release, Kepler, will be released on June 26, 2013. Juno, current release, was released on June 27, 2012.

Comment: @logoff Keeping fingers crossed .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible nowadays. Many people wants it (including me) since 2002 as it is a [feature request since then](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23295). Try asking again for it.

Comment: I upvoted the issue... And now we wait. There are comments with the date of today that say: "(In reply to comment #25)
> Could be in the next big release, Kepler? It is a requests since 2002... It would help many developers.

Only if someone provides a high quality patch."

Comment: @Timo these are my comments to remind them it! but I don't have the skills to develop the patch...

Comment: Thanks for bumping the issue! I don't have the time to develop such a patch and added a copy-paste for completeness.

Comment: Just FYI: Googling "Eclipse Move Breakpoint" brought up this question _and_ the feature request mentioned here. Unfortunately, they still seem to be waiting for a 'high quality patch'. :-(

Comment: It's been "assigned" but there have been no comments, still, since back in 2013

Comment: Still in "assigned" in 2021. Oh my gosh!